# link metamask wallet to my shopping site

Tags: blockchain, metamask, mining, synchronization, meta-transactions

I have an nftmarket site. How do I link Metamask wallet to transact on my site.
Artists will sell nft through my site, so how do I connect the metamask?

Answer (score 0):

I give you basic and simplest code for connect metamask form using `ethers`. For more ways to connect metamask wallet read you can prefer is [metamask docs](https://docs.metamask.io/guide/ethereum-provider.html).

```
import {ethers} from 'ethers'

const connectWalletHandler = () => {
        if (window.ethereum && window.ethereum.isMetaMask) {
            console.log('MetaMask Here!');

            window.ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts'})
            .then(result => {
                accountChangedHandler(result[0]);
                setConnButtonText('Wallet Connected');
                getAccountBalance(result[0]);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                setErrorMessage(error.message);
            
            });

        } else {
            console.log('Need to install MetaMask');
            setErrorMessage('Please install MetaMask browser extension to interact');
        }
    }
```

Comment: thank you can you send me your e-mail I want to talk to you or can you give me your watsapp number

Comment: Sorry but I can't give you my whatsapp number.

Comment: can you email me i want help